# Seaborn duplicate legend entries

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

When plotting multiple histograms using `seaborn` like so:

```
sns.histplot(df_submissions[df_submissions.link_flair_text == 'Meme'].body.str.len(), binwidth=50, stat='percent', label='Meme')
sns.histplot(df_submissions[df_submissions.link_flair_text == 'News'].body.str.len(), binwidth=50, stat='percent', label='News')
sns.histplot(df_submissions[df_submissions.link_flair_text == 'Discussion'].body.str.len(), binwidth=50, stat='percent', label='Discussion')
plt.legend()
```

there is a [duplicate legend entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlmWV.png) for every histogram. Is there a *simple* solution using `seaborn`?

Things I've tried:

- calling `sns.histplot` with `legend=False` -> same result
- calling `sns.histplot` with `legend=True` and omitting the call to `plt.legend()` -> no legend
- removing the `label=x` parameter and calling `plt.legend` with `labels=[...]` -> legend wrong colour

I know `get_legend_handles_labels` is a potential workaround but that seems like a hack.

Comment: Note that seaborn only provides a legend when you create the plot in one go, using `hue`.  The unhacky seaborn way would be `sns.histplot(x=df_submissions['body'].str.len(), hue=df_submissions['link_flair_text'], 
common_norm=False, stat=..., binwidth=...)`.  Another option would be to upgrade to the latest version of Seaborn (0.12.2) which shouldn't create two elements per histogram anymore.

Comment: See https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3115